# ESPTOOL not recognizing ESP32-S2 chip for SPIFFs transfer

Tags: esp32, espressif, spiffs

I have a spiff file that uploads fine using a regular esp32, but when I try on the esp32-32, with a fresh installation, I get:

esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM3
Connecting....

A fatal error occurred: This chip is ESP32-S2 not ESP32. Wrong --chip argument?
SPIFFS Upload failed!

Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: you forgot to show the executed esptool command in question

Comment: Arduino does it for you, but I also tried: esptool.py -chip esp32s2 -port COM3 -baud 115200 write_flash -z ox110000 filename.spiffs.bin

Comment: maybe you have to specify the S2 for the spiffs tool

Comment: I tried, but no luck

Comment: Look at the espressif documentation here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s2/api-guides/build-system.html#selecting-idf-target and see if this provides a workable solution. MN

Comment: Actually we are at v3.1, cannot you upgrade to it? Maybe it's a bug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the missing double dash?

```
esptool.py --chip esp32s2 --port COM3 --baud 115200 write_flash -z 0x110000 filename.spiffs.bin
```